# Conditional jQuery applying css to elements regardless of condition being met

Tags: jquery, css

I can't figure out why my function is applying the CSS transform to the elements whose characters are greater than 17? I have included both the html and css, but it will encounter many of these grids, and i hope to move the text of a h2 element up slightly if it's character count is less than 17.

only problem is that it is applying the css regardless of the amount of characters.

can anyone help?
thank you

html

```
<div class="fancy_diamonds three_line text-center">
  <div class="woocommerce columns-3">
    <ul class="products columns-3">
      <li class="product-category product first">
        <div class="banner-box">
          <div class="banner-box__image">
            <a href="https://website/product-category/construction/">
              <span class="woocommerce-loop-category__thumbnail" style="background-image :url(https://website/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/services1-2-600x326.jpg);"></span></a>

          </div>
          <div class="banner-box__info">

            <a href="https://website/product-category/construction/">

              <h2 class="woocommerce-loop-category__title">

                Construction
              </h2>

            </a>

          </div>

        </div>
      </li>

      <li class="product-category product">
        <div class="banner-box">
          <div class="banner-box__image">
            <a href="https://website/product-category/controlled-hygiene/window-cleaning/">
              <span class="woocommerce-loop-category__thumbnail" style="background-image :url(https://website/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/store-smaller.jpg);"></span></a>

          </div>
          <div class="banner-box__info">

            <a href="https://website/product-category/controlled-hygiene/window-cleaning/">

              <h2 class="woocommerce-loop-category__title">

                window cleaning
              </h2>

            </a>

          </div>

        </div>
      </li>

      <li class="product-category product last">
        <div class="banner-box">
          <div class="banner-box__image">
            <a href="https://website/product-category/workwear-safety/">
              <span class="woocommerce-loop-category__thumbnail" style="background-image :url(https://website/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/workwear.jpg);"></span></a>

          </div>
          <div class="banner-box__info">

            <a href="https://website/product-category/workwear-safety/">

              <h2 class="woocommerce-loop-category__title">

                Workwear &amp; Safety
              </h2>

            </a>

          </div>

        </div>
      </li>

    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

  jQuery(".fancy_diamonds.three_line .woocommerce ul.products li:nth-child(3) .banner-box__info h2").each(function() {

    var charLength = jQuery(this).find("h2.woocommerce-loop-category__title").text().length;
    var newLength = charLength - 47; // This is another issue, it counts the html for some reason 
    if (newLength < 17) {
      jQuery(this).css({
        "transform": "translatey(-150%)"
      });
    } else {
      jQuery(this).css({
        "transform": "none"
      });
    }
  });

});
```

Comment: Your first query `$("...h2")` finds the h2, but your 2nd query then attempts to find another `h2` *inside* that h2 `$("..h2").find("h2")` so finds *nothing*.     Given the provided html and jquery.   So charLength is always === 0, so it's always applied.  If you fix the selector, then you probably just want `.text().trim().length` to remove the *whitespace* (not HTML as you stated, there's no HTML).

Comment: thank you the trim solved the extra characters problem. however, i made the changes you suggested to the selectors. How can i say don't make any changes, rather than transform: none for the else part?

Comment: Just remove the `else` part?

Comment: For some reason, unless i have transform none for the else part, it will always apply the css style for the first condition, regardless of the condition being met. very strange i know.

Comment: i got it to work - i think the issue was another transform i had on the element. thank you for your help.